# Difference in differentiation between Mathematica and Wolfram Alpha

Tags: calculus, derivatives, mathematica, wolfram-alpha

I am trying to differentiate this:
$$f(x)=e^{-x^2}$$

In Wolfram Alpha I get this:
$$-2x\,e^{-x^2}$$

But in Mathematica I get:
$$-2x\,e^{-x^2}\log(e)$$

Why the difference?

Comment: What is $ e $ ?

Comment: Here's a clue: if you ask Mathematica to differentiate, say, $g^{-x^2}$, then what you get is $-2xg^{-x^2}\log(g)$.

Comment: In Mathematica, the constant $e$ is denoted with a capital E. If you use a lowercase e, it will assume that's a variable named e. Or you can use Exp[].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is in notation.

Mathematica, by convention, only assigns special meaning to identifiers that begin with a capital letter, not lowercase. In particular, [the mathematical constant $e$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)) is represented as `E` in Mathematica - when you type it in. When it appears in output, it is written as "" to distinguish it.

[image: Mathematica input/output for the derivatives of E^-x^2 and e^-x^2]

A lowercase `e` in Mathematica has no special meaning: it is a variable, just like `f` or `g`. Mathematica treats it as a variable: you can tell because of the syntax highlighting. If `e` were equal to `E`, then `Log[e]` would simplify to `1` and go away.